# Reactive Mailer - blocking operation on a IO thread

Tags: java, asynchronous, vert.x, quarkus

With reactive mailer I am trying to persist if the email was succeeded or not.
Here down the code snippet that is not woking:

```
@Path("atendimentos")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AtendimentoResource {
    @Inject
    AtendimentoHistoricoRepository atendimentoHistoricoRepository;
    @Inject
    ReactiveMailer mailer;
    @GET
    public Response findAll(@QueryParam("nome") String nome) {
    AtendimentoHistorico atendimentoHistorico = new AtendimentoHistorico();
       mailer.send(email).subscribe().with(success -> {
           atendimentoHistorico.setEmailEnviado(true);
           atendimentoHistoricoRepository.persist(atendimentoHistorico);
         }, error -> {
       });
    }
}
```

Here is the thrown exception:

You have attempted to perform a blocking operation on a IO thread. This is not allowed, as blocking the IO thread will cause major performance issues with your application. If you want to perform blocking EntityManager operations make sure you are doing it from a worker thread.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.
Could you please provide the whole code snipped?
Where and how is the `mailer` code executed?

Comment: Done, updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block, you should use `io.quarkus.mailer.Mailer` instead of `ReactiveMailer`.

```
@Path("atendimentos")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class AtendimentoResource {
    @Inject
    AtendimentoHistoricoRepository atendimentoHistoricoRepository;
    @Inject
    Mailer mailer;
    @GET
    public Response findAll(@QueryParam("nome") String nome) {
    AtendimentoHistorico atendimentoHistorico = new AtendimentoHistorico();
       mailer.send(email);
       atendimentoHistorico.setEmailEnviado(true);
       atendimentoHistoricoRepository.persist(atendimentoHistorico);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do an update in the database, but I would like the email to be assync. Is that possible?

Comment: According to the description of the question, you are trying to update the database after the email has been sent, correct?

Comment: Correct, but asynchronally